# Why does Eclipse always give me an error after return;

Tags: java, eclipse

I have some problem with eclipse android.

I have some java files, but if I call a method after return; (see the example) it tells me to remove the method. Why? I'm using Android 1.6.

```
public void onClick(View paramView)
 {
  switch (paramView.getId())
{
default:
case 2131296257:
}
while (true)
{
  return;
  fetchAlarmSettings();  <-- It tells me to remove this.
  if (this.strAlarmOnOff.equals("0"))
  {
    this.butAlarmSet.setText("Turn Alarm Off");
    this.db.updateSetting("alarmTime", this.strHour.concat(this.strMinute));
    this.db.updateSetting("alarmOnOff", "1");
    switch (this.cal.compareTo(Calendar.getInstance()))
    {
    default:
    case -1:
    }
    while (true)
    {
      this.setNotifications.setAlarm(this.cal);
      break;
      this.cal.roll(5, 1);
    }
  }
  this.butAlarmSet.setText("Turn Alarm On");
  this.db.updateSetting("alarmOnOff", "0");
  this.setNotifications.turnAlarmOff();
}
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because the method ( and the rest of the code inside the while loop) will never be executed

Comment: This is not an android thing. It's basic java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method will stop running the moment that the `return` statement is hit. Basically it should give you an '`Unreachable code!`' warning, since any code after the return statement will never be executed. Removing the `return` keyword should fix the problem.

So basically Eclipse is telling you to remove the next line after the `return` since it will never be executed. If you remove the method call it will complain over what ever line you throw in next.

Besides that, there are other (according to me) flaws with your code... having a `while(true)` loop without a break condition in this case seems odd (but then again I might be wrong here). Also, the `default` block is usually found at the end of a series of `case` statements. Your second `while(true)` loop will only iterate once since once the `this.setNotifications.setAlarm(this.cal);` is executed the loop will stop iterating due to the `break` statement.

Comment: Same as the `break` there in this example.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: Eclipse should flag it as an error however, when you try and compile the compilation will fail.

Comment: Either way, that `return` does not belong there. All the code that appears after it is inaccessible, so it's useless.

Comment: @npinti didn't get your comment sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse will not allow you to write obsolute code, actually the IDE uses java compiler for that.

In this case the code below the return in certain branch (meaning that you can have return in the `if` and after it code for the `else`) is not reachable and thus you get compile error.

Comment: Code such as `if( true ) return;` will be allowed and only produce a warning though.

Comment: True, however code in which in certain branch something follows after return is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, you can  not perform any operation after 'return' statement.